# How does sizeToFit determine appropriate size?

Tags: ios, sizetofit

I have an app where the user can add what I call palettes at will. Items (`UIViews`) can be dragged from one palette to another. I thought I could use the `sizeToFit` method to automatically resize the palettes when items were added ore removed, but no resizing seems to be happening.

The documentation states that the method resizes to the most appropriate size to fit the subviews. Does that not include `UIViews` that I add programmatically?

I'd really not have to write my own `sizeToFit` method if I can get the built-in one to work for me. But it seems to be doing nothing. Here's the code I've tried:

```
        CGPoint oldCenter = self.pieceBeingMoved.center;
        CGPoint newCenter = [self.pieceBeingMoved.superview convertPoint:oldCenter toView:destinationView];
        [destinationView addSubview:self.pieceBeingMoved];
        self.pieceBeingMoved.center = newCenter;
        if (destinationView.tag == 20000) {
           NSLog(@"DestinationView is a palette, so resize it from %@",NSStringFromCGRect(destinationView.frame));
           [destinationView sizeToFit];
           NSLog(@"DestinationView resized to %@",NSStringFromCGRect(destinationView.frame));
        }
```

The size is identical before and after the subview is added. The subview being added is the only subview at the time I ran this test, and the size of the subview is about 5% the size of the palette it is being moved to. So why isn't the view being resized? Do I need to do it myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sizeToFit` method just calls `sizeThatFits:` and then resizes the view accordingly. The default implementation of the UIView class returns the current size so you don’t see any effect. You will have to write your own `sizeThatFits:` method to do your calculation.

Comment: I'm still struggling to understand how this works. It sounds like I need to subclass my view in order to write a sizeThatFits: method if I'm going to use sizeToFit on it. Is that right? I think it would be easier to simply write a method to reset the frame in my controller, and then I don't have to worry about subclassing. Am I missing something?

Comment: Right, if you want to use sizeToFit you’ll have to subclass UIView. You can also implement this functionality in a view controller. It all depends on how you want to use your view.

Comment: One other question. If I do the coding myself in the view controller, I assume that besides changing the frame of the view, I'll have to change the frames of all its subviews, too. Is that done automatically by sizeToFit? I wish the documentation had more details on how these methods actually work.

Comment: @VictorEngel Seems to me your question has been answered. If you have a further question, ask a new question...

Comment: @matt, I'm pretty sure if I created a question that asked if subviews of a view being resized with sizeToFit automatically reset the frames of the subviews, it would be closed as not a real question. It's really intimately related to my original question, so I think it belongs here.

Comment: The problem is that you asked a loaded question - a question about `sizeToFit` only. That is the direction *you* chose to go, and now you've been told about that. A different, better question might be to describe your situation better and *ask* what direction to go.

Comment: @matt, I don't want to beat a dead horse, but it's implied in the wording of the documentation: "Resizes and moves the receiver view so it just encloses its subviews." That seems to indicate that the frame of the view will be brought in to just enclose its subviews. If it did that, the frame origin would move, so to keep the subviews stationary, their centers would have to be adjusted since they are in terms of the parent view's coordinate system. My followup question is a continuation of this very thing which I addressed in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an idea. *Don't* call `sizeToFit`. Just set the frame to the frame you actually want.

Comment: Unfortunately, that requires looking at the sizes and positions of all the subviews. I thought sizeToFit was looking at that. The documentation seems to indicate that. If it did, that would have saved some effort. You know what they say, don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: There isn't any wheel. A UIView subclass that you create doesn't automatically know what size you want it to be. You have to tell it somehow.

Comment: OK. But the documentation implies that it does know: "Resizes and moves the receiver view so it just encloses its subviews." The size I want it to be is the size that just encloses the subviews.